# iOS - 2D line drawing on negative coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I am developing an app in which user can draw lines. The desktop version of the same app is able to draw lines on negative coordinates and I would like to have same capability in iOS app too.

What I've tried so far:-
I have a `UIViewController` inside which I have overridden `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` and drawn the line. Here is the code I am using:-

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(self.startHandle.frame.origin.x + self.startHandle.frame.size.width/2, self.startHandle.frame.origin.y + self.startHandle.frame.size.height/2);

CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(self.endHandle.frame.origin.x + self.endHandle.frame.size.width/2, self.endHandle.frame.origin.y + self.endHandle.frame.size.height/2);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0f);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y ); //start at this point
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x, endPoint.y); //draw to this point
```

It works very well until I have `startPoint.x` as a negative value. With negative  value, I don't see the portion of line that is behind 0,0 coordinates. Any help or information is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from what @matt said (he has since deleted his answer, shame as it was still useful), you simply want to apply a transform to the context in order to draw in a standard cartesian coordinate system, where `(0,0)` is the center of the screen.

**The context provided to you from within `drawRect` has its origin at the top left of the screen, with the positive y-direction going down the screen.**

[image]

So first, we'll want to first flip the y-axis so that the positive y-direction goes up the screen.

**We can do this by using `CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1)`. This will reflect the y-axis of the context.** Therefore, this reflected context will have a y-axis where the positive direction goes up the screen.

[image]

Next, we want to translate the context to the correct position, so that `(0,0)` corresponds to the center of the screen. We should therefore shift the y-axis down by half of the height (so that `0` on the y-axis is now at the center), and the x-axis to the right by half of the width.

**We can do this by using `CGContextTranslateCTM(context, width*0.5, -height*0.5)`, where `width` and `height` are the width and height of your view respectively.**

Now your context coordinates will look like this:

[image]

**You could implement this into your `drawRect` like so:**

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat width = self.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.bounds.size.height;

    // scale and translate to the standard cartesian coordinate system where the (0,0) is the center of the screen.
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, width*0.5, -height*0.5);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0);

    // add y-axis
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, -height*0.5);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 0, height*0.5);

    // add x-axis
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, -width*0.5, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, width*0.5, 0);

    // stroke axis
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);


    // define start and end points
    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(-100, 100);
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(100, -200);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, startPoint.x, startPoint.y );
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

**This will give the following output:**

[image]

I added the red lines to represent the y and x axis, in order to clarify what we've done here.

Comment: Did this help @Ankur-Arora?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);
```

You can draw out of this bounds,please make a larger rect.

Comment: you mean change self.bounds.origin.x to negative value?

Comment: @AnkurArora I meant the canvas is so small that your draw outside,make a larger one whose origin will be negative.

Comment: I am unable to understand what do you mean. If I increase the canvas size how that will help line to be drawn on negative coordinates? Because with the canvas size point (0,0) also changes. Could you please share a sample code for what you are trying to explain?

Comment: @AnkurArora He means that the top left of the context is (0,0) so negative x is off to the left beyond the context and negative y is off to the top above the context. You can't draw outside the context so you can't see that drawing.

Comment: I understand the theory but I do not know how to solve it practically. Could you please share the code where position of my parent view stays intact but line drawn inside this parent is supporting negative coordinates?